# "nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" with shell script

Tags: shell, terminal, netcat

I'm trying to communicate with my server and send telnet commands (login and logout again). For this I generated a shell skript and getting the error message "**nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known**".

The specific line is:

```
(sleep 1&echo $login&sleep 1&echo $password&sleep 1&echo exit) | nc $IP 23 > dump.out
```

When I execute this line (and for sure the export lines before) directly in the terminal it works without any problem, but when I execute the script, I get the error message.

Can anyone help? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a question for ServerFault.com

Comment: do you want to use double ampersands as in `&&`?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

**nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided**

*This error means netcat was unable to look up the requested host in DNS. Usually this means you either have a typo somewhere, or your the pagekite.py connector on the SSH server side is not running properly.*

Try to check your packages, something is either wrong with your script or the DNS request.

Hope it helps! :)

Source: http://pagekite.net/wiki/Howto/SshOverPageKite/#ncdns